# Defining a function on an interval

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Fairly basic question, but one I can't seem to find an answer to- How can I define a function *f(x)* on an *x* interval *[0, 10]*?

Comment: There is a Stack Exchange site dedicated to wolfram mathematica. On there I found this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163746/how-to-restrict-the-domain-of-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are almost always several different ways of writing anything using Mathematica.

One way is:

```
f[x_]:=Piecewise[{{x^2,0<=x<=10}}]
```

which will have the value x^2 over [0,10] and 0 elsewhere. You can look at the documentation for `Piecewise` and see how you can change the value elsewhere.

Another way is

```
f[x_/;0<=x<=10]:=x^2
```

which will have the value x^2 over [0,10] and f[x] elsewhere. You can look at the documentation for `/;` (also called `Condition`) and see how that is define.

Another way is

```
f[x_]:=If[0<=x<=10,x^2]
```